# Can't reach local image when creating word document using java

Tags: java

I'm creating a word document which datas came from access database. I want to create header and footer section and I want to put in it a image. But I get this error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\images\page1_header.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.start_page_1(access_connection.java:387)
    at access_read_and_write.access_connection.Start(access_connection.java:161)
    at Servlet.shop_visit_report.doGet(shop_visit_report.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My codes likes this

```
public static void start_page_1(String SalesOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException
    {
        XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy  headerpol = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();
        XWPFTable headerpictable= header.createTable(0,0);
        headerpictable.removeBorders();
        headerpictable.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
        XWPFTableRow row5;
        XWPFTableCell cell5;
        CTDrawing drawing;
        CTAnchor anchor;
        row5=headerpictable.getRow(0);
        cell5=row5.getCell(0);
        headerpictable.setCellMargins(0, 0, 0, 500);
        headerpictable.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.LEFT);
        headerpictable.setWidthType(TableWidthType.PCT);
        CTTrPr trPr;
        CTHeight ht;
        CTTblWidth cellwidth;
        CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
        XWPFParagraph paragpic=document.createParagraph();
        paragpic.setSpacingBetween(0);
        paragpic=cell5.getParagraphArray(0);
        XWPFRun r1=paragpic.createRun();
     /* File file = new File(imgFile);
        InputStream pic = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream pic = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile));
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(imgFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        InputStream pic = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
        InputStream pic = access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream(imgFile);
        InputStream pic = new URL(imgFile).openStream();
        r1.addPicture(pic, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(90)); */
        XWPFTable imagetalbe = document.createTable(0,0);
        CTTblLayoutType type1 = imagetalbe.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
        type1.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
        CTTblLayoutType type3 = headerpictable.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
        type3.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
        imagetalbe.setTopBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setBottomBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setLeftBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");
        imagetalbe.setRightBorder(XWPFBorderType.THREE_D_ENGRAVE, 10, 0, "C6DCF0");  
        XWPFParagraph parag = document.createParagraph();   
        XWPFTableRow row2;
        XWPFTableCell cell2;
        row2=imagetalbe.getRow(0);
        cell2=row2.getCell(0);
        parag=cell2.addParagraph();            
        parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
        parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment. AUTO);
        XWPFRun runimagetable = parag.createRun();
        cell2.setColor("FFFFFF");
        cell2.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
        cell2.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((short)25));
        trPr = row2.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
        ht = trPr.addNewTrHeight();     
        ht.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(-5000));                               
        try {
            FileInputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(new File(imgFile2));          
            runimagetable.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));
            parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
            parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);
            XWPFParagraph parag2=document.createParagraph(); 
            XWPFRun runn= parag2.createRun();
            runn.setFontFamily("Calibri");
            runn.setFontSize(45);
            runn.setColor("0A719B");
            runn.setShadow(true);      
            parag2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            runn.setText("SHOP VISIT REPORT");
            XWPFTable table2=document.createTable(0,0);
            XWPFTable table1=document.createTable(11,4);
            table2.removeBorders();
            table2.setLeftBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20, 0, "090A09");
            table2.setRightBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20, 0, "090A09");
            table2.setTopBorder(XWPFBorderType.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP, 20,0 , "090A09");
            table1.removeInsideHBorder();
            table1.removeInsideVBorder();
            CTTblLayoutType type,type2;
            table1.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
            type = table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();  
            type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
            table2.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.CENTER);
            type2 = table2.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout(); 
            type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);    
            XWPFTableRow row;
            XWPFTableCell cell; 
            parag=document.createParagraph();
            CTTrPr trPr2;
            CTHeight ht2;
            row=table2.getRow(0);
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag=cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            XWPFRun run = parag.createRun();
            cell.setColor("BCDFD5");
            cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
            cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((short)6));
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-800)));
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("ENGINE INFORMATION");
            run.setFontSize(20);
            run.setFontFamily("Calibri");
            run.setBold(true);
            parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);  
            row=table1.getRow(0);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            cell.setText(" Customer");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            CTSdtRun ctSdtRun = parag.getCTP().addNewSdt();
            CTSdtComboBox ctSdtComboBox = ctSdtRun.addNewSdtPr().addNewComboBox();
            CTSdtListItem ctSdtListItem = ctSdtComboBox.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem.setDisplayText("please select an option");
            ctSdtListItem.setValue("please select an option");
            ctSdtListItem = ctSdtComboBox.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem.setDisplayText("one");
            ctSdtListItem.setValue("one");    
            ctSdtRun.addNewSdtContent().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("choose an item.");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2500)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("MODEL");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000)); 
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":V2527-AQ03");
            row=table1.getRow(1);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Engine S/N");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":V12492");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("S/O NO");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":"+ SalesOrder);
            row=table1.getRow(2);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" A/C Reg.");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("A/C Type");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":A320 Family");
            row=table1.getRow(3);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" TSN");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("CSN");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            row=table1.getRow(4);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" TSLSV");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("CSLSV");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":999999");
            row=table1.getRow(6);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Reason for Removal");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":Over Inspection Per ESEO");
            row=table1.getRow(7);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Induction Date");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            parag.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("DATE \\@ \"yyyy-MM-dd\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
            row=table1.getRow(9);
            trPr2 = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
            ht2 = trPr2.addNewTrHeight();
            ht2.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((-300)));
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText( " Prepared By");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            CTSdtRun ctSdtRun2 = parag.getCTP().addNewSdt();
            CTSdtComboBox ctSdtComboBox2 = ctSdtRun2.addNewSdtPr().addNewComboBox();
            CTSdtListItem ctSdtListItem2 = ctSdtComboBox2.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem2.setDisplayText("choose an item");
            ctSdtListItem2.setValue("choose an item");
            ctSdtListItem2 = ctSdtComboBox2.addNewListItem();
            ctSdtListItem2.setDisplayText("one");
            ctSdtListItem2.setValue("one");    
            ctSdtRun2.addNewSdtContent().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("choose an item.");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("R.O No.");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            row=table1.getRow(10);
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(" Prepared Date");
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            parag.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("DATE \\@ \"yyyy-MM-dd\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
            cell=row.getCell(2);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText("Rev. No.");
            cell=row.getCell(3);
            parag= cell.getParagraphArray(0);
            run =  parag.createRun();
            run.setText(":");
            for(int i =0;i<11;i++){
                row=table1.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {cell=row.getCell(j);
                cell.setColor("BCDFD5");
                }
            }

            table1.removeBorders();
            CTTblPr tblpro = table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
            CTTblBorders borders = tblpro.addNewTblBorders();
            borders.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP); 
            borders.addNewLeft().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP);
            borders.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.THIN_THICK_THIN_MEDIUM_GAP);
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            table1.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(20));
            FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(word_saveas_file);
            document.write(input);
            input.close();        
            System.out.println("basarii");
                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

The image in my workspace folder. WebContent -> Resources -> images -> page1_header.png that is my image path. Why I can't reach this image??

Comment: You can't change target folder while running program because it is generated while building the program. So, you should specifiy file path under the external folder that out of the target folder.

Comment: How is `imgFile2` defined?  Is it a constant?

Comment: @VGR I defined imgFile2 like this `public static String imgFile2 = "resources\\images\\page1_header.png";`

Comment: Change it to `public static final String imgFile2 = "images/page1_header.png";` (forward slash, not backslash), and read it with `InputStream is2 = access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream(imgFile2);`.  Resources are not guaranteed to be physical files in a packaged program.

Comment: @VGR I made it that you said but I get this error `java.lang.NullPointerException` in this code `runimagetable.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));`

Comment: If `getResourceAsStream` returns null, if means your resources aren’t packaged in your .war file with your classes.